# User Permissions in Ubuntu

Tags: permissions, root, sudo, ubuntu-14.04, sudoers

I want to access "sudoers" file and also access "su -" but I fail and get following error please check terminal output that I have tried. I am m-usman(admin) but not allow to edit or access ? :(

```
m-usman@muhammad-usman:~$ sudo gedit /etc/sudoers
[sudo] password for m-usman:        
m-usman is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
m-usman@muhammad-usman:~$ su -
Password:   
su: Authentication failure
m-usman@muhammad-usman:~$ sudo visudo
[sudo] password for m-usman: 
m-usman is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: you must ask your sysadmin

Comment: Sir i am using my own system and My user name is m-usman

Comment: do you have the root password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your user account has not been added to the sudoers file, hence you don’t have permission to edit the sudoers file or switch to super user.

Ask somebody (who already is in sudoers list) to add you in the sudoers list. and then you will have the appropriate permissions to do stuffs using sudo.

Thanks.